# Z-Index in iframe

Tags: jquery, object, iframe, z-index

I have a object tag (flash) within a iframe tag, which is within a page .Aspx. But in this .aspx page, I have two combobox, and when the combobox is expanded, the options that are displayed are behind the object tag (flash) which is in iframe tag.

I tried in the CSS put a z-index temporarily with a high value in combobox and a low value in iframe, but did not work.

Somebody can help me ?

Answer (score 0):

Set the wmode property of flash object to opaque.

```
<param name="wmode" value="opaque" />
```

Answer (score 0):

also try to set positions as well with the z indexes, like absolute etc.

plus you use

```
<param NAME="wmode" VALUE="transparent">
```

hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

The `<param>` I can see just when the page is rendered (runnig), so I think I can't set this.

This is my code with the `<iframe>`

`<div class="fundo-passagem" style="padding-top:27px;">
        <iframe runat="server" id="ifConteudo" name="ifConteudo" frameborder="0" height="790px"
                                width="960px" class="iframeInstitucional" style="position:inherit;">
        </iframe>
 </div>`

Answer (score 0):

The z-index works fine against the `<iframe>` but against the `<object>` didn't work. The `<object>` are inside the `<iframe>` but just when the page are rendered.